# UCD books for a Product Designer?

Tags: industrial-design

My brother, who is a Product Designer, has become interested in User-Centred Design through my preachings and has been reading my Donald Norman books.

Can anyone recommend any books that touch on user-centred industrial design?

[Designing Pleasurable Products](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0415298873) looks like it might fit the bill, though I've not read it myself.

Answer (score 6):

There is a good range of experience available in [Designing Interactions](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Designing-Interactions-B-Moggridge/dp/0262134748/ref=pd_sim_b_4)

Comment: noob here: how can I make the link in my answer display as the book title? yes I did look at meta and FAQs but not obvious to me...

Comment: Select the text you want to make into a link and then click the link icon in the toolbar (globe with an arrow) or press CTRL-L and then paste in your URL.

Comment: Thanks Pete. The markdown seems to need a reference to the link, as in [link caption][1]

[1] link URL

Comment: You may also use HTML: <a href="URL">CAPTION</a>

Answer (score 5):

I would strongly recommend [Objects of Desire](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Objects-Desire-Design-Society-Since/dp/0500274126/) by Adrian Forty. This book is about the history of industrial design and about it's place in society. It's insightful and engaging and fascinating. Though you wouldn't find the phrase 'user-centered' in it, it's absolutely worth reading for every product designer.

Answer (score 4):

This isn't a book, but you can ask him to watch Gary Hustwit's [Objectified](http://www.objectifiedfilm.com/)... and even [Helvetica](http://www.helveticafilm.com/) :)

Answer (score 3):

I found Bill Buxton's [Sketching User Experiences](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0123740371) quite an interesting read, especially for the more explorative first part of product development.

Answer (score 3):

You and he might also be interested in checking out Marty Cagan's book [Inspired: How to Create Products Customers Love.](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0981690408)

While not about UCD per-se, it contains insightful materials about such things as product management vs. design, product discovery, personas for product management, prototype testing, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Having read this interview with [Jonathan Ive](http://www.thisislondon.co.uk/lifestyle/london-life/sir-jonathan-ive-the-iman-cometh-7562170.html):

*A: One of the things we’ve really learnt over the last 20 years is that while people would often struggle to articulate why they like something - as consumers we are incredibly discerning, we sense where has been great care in the design, and when there is cynicism and greed. It’s one of the thing we’ve found really encouraging.*

I'd also suggest this (in a rather left field kind of way)

[Zen and the Art of Motorcycle Maintenance: An Inquiry into Values](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zen_and_the_Art_of_Motorcycle_Maintenance)